# How to create identity in MVC app with JWT

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity-2, jwt

I'll try to be explicit.

I have a Front End app (MVC), it can communicate with a Facade Web Api (Resource) and get token from an authentication server.

My problem is I can't create an identity in MVC app. This is mu Startup class.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        });

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions 
        {

        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    }
```

When I try to go to a method controller decorated with [Authorize], I get 401 error instead to be redirected to Login page.

Please, I would appreciate any help, advice or example.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, unless your app is doing postback's you do not need to enable the cookie authentication with login path.  That is for the oauth password login flow (grant_type) where you are internally authorizing your users against your identity database.  If you're redirecting to an external authorization api (like facebook) then you don't need to set a login path in your application since the first authorization endpoint that gets hit is your external callback (after you send them to facebook, they will send them back to your external endpoint).  The redirect you are getting is because cookie authentication is registered as active authentication mode so it redirects 401's to the login path you set (overriding other OWIN middleware).

If you want to house your authorization server in house, have a look at the link below, it will at the least get you setup with JWT support -

http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/